# Is there a way to take all of my row values and make them col headers?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matrix

I currently have a long list of countries (234 values). For simplicity sake, picture [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KjLOX.png) displays only 10. This is what my df currently looks like:

[image: current df]

I want to create a matrix of some sort, where *the countries listed in each row* are also the *col headers*. This is what I want my output dataframe to look like:

| Country | China | India | U.S | Indonesia | Pakistan | ... | Montserrat | Falkland Islands | Niue | Tokelau | Vatican City |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| China |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| India |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| U.S. |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Indonesia |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Pakistan |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| ... |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Montserrat |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Falkland Islands |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Niue |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Tokelau |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Vatican City |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

So to reiterate the question, how do I take the value in each row of col 1 and copy it to be my dataframe column headers to create a matrix. This dataframe is also being scraped from a website using requests and beautiful soup, so it isn't like i can create a csv file of a pre-made dataframe. Is what I want to do possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will something like this work?

```py
data = ["US","China","England","Spain",'Brazil']
df = pd.DataFrame({"Country":data})
df[df.Country.values] = ''
df
```

Output:

```
   Country  US  China   England Spain   Brazil
0   US                  
1   China                   
2   England                 
3   Spain                   
4   Brazil
```

You can even set the country as the index like:

```
data = [1,2,3,4,5]
df = pd.DataFrame({"Country":data})
df[df.Country.values] = ''
df = df.set_index(df.Country)[df.Country.values].rename_axis(index=None)
```

Output:

```
        US  China   England Spain   Brazil
US                  
China                   
England                 
Spain                   
Brazil
```

Answer (score 1):

Initialize a Pandas DataFrame as follows

```py
countryList = ['China', 'India', 'U.S.']

pd.DataFrame(columns=countryList, index=countryList)
```

and just append all elements of ```countryList`` according to your use case. This yields an empty dataframe to insert data into.

|  | China | India | U.S. |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| China | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| India | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| U.S. | NaN | NaN | NaN |

Answer (score 0):

7Shoe's answer is good, but in case you already have a dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.DataFrame({'Country':['U.S.','Canada', 'India']})
pd.DataFrame(columns=df.Country, index=df.Country).rename_axis(None)
```

Output

```
Country U.S. Canada India
U.S.     NaN    NaN   NaN
Canada   NaN    NaN   NaN
India    NaN    NaN   NaN
```